# Value is undefined from action while using react-redux, instead of payload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am building an app using React, React-redux, Redux, Express, and Sequelize for a project for school.

In my other views I got the data back, to insert and update my view accordingly, but in this case I'm getting **undefined**.

I just switched from redux to react-redux so I apologize in advance!

This is a screenshot of my console:

[image]

This my reducer for the SingleCountry, with my action creators and thunks...

```
'use strict';

import axios from 'axios';

// ACTION TYPES
const GET_COUNTRY = 'GET_COUNTRY';

// ACTION CREATORS
export function getCountry(oneCountry) {
  const action = {
    type: GET_COUNTRY,
    oneCountry,
  };
  return action;
}

//THUNK CREATORS

export function fetchCountry(countryId) {
  return function thunk(dispatch) {
    return axios
      .get('/api/countries/' + `${countryId}`)
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(country => {
        const action = getCountry(country);
        dispatch(action);
      });
  };
}

// REDUCER
const reducer = function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_COUNTRY:
      return action.oneCountry;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

This is the reducer for Countries:

```
'use strict';

import axios from 'axios';

// ACTION TYPES
const GET_COUNTRIES = 'GET_COUNTRIES';

// ACTION CREATORS
export function getCountries(countries) {
  const action = {
    type: GET_COUNTRIES,
    countries,
  };
  return action;
}

//THUNK CREATORS
export function fetchCountries() {
  return function thunk(dispatch) {
    return axios
      .get('/api/countries')
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(countries => dispatch(getCountries(countries)))
      .catch(console.error);
  };
}

// REDUCER
const reducer = function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_COUNTRIES:
      return action.countries;
    // return { ...state, countries: action.countries };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

And this is the reducer for the TopFiveCountries:

```
'use strict';

import axios from 'axios';

// ACTION TYPES
const GET_TOP_COUNTRIES_BY_GFI = 'GET_TOP_COUNTRIES_BY_GFI';

// ACTION CREATORS
export function getTopFiveCountriesByGFI(topFiveCountries) {
  const action = {
    type: GET_TOP_COUNTRIES_BY_GFI,
    topFiveCountries,
  };
  return action;
}

//THUNK CREATORS
export function fetchTopFiveCountriesByGFI() {
  return function thunk(dispatch) {
    return axios
      .get('/api/countries/top-five-countries')
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(countries => {
        const action = getTopFiveCountriesByGFI(countries);
        dispatch(action);
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  };
}

// REDUCER
const reducer = function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_TOP_COUNTRIES_BY_GFI:
      return action.topFiveCountries;
    // return { ...state, topFiveCountries: action.topFiveCountries };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

This the view for SingleCountry question:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { fetchCountry } from '../reducers/oneCountry';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store';

class SingleCountry extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const flagStyle = {
      height: '50px',
      width: '100px',
    };

    const oneCountry = this.props.oneCountry;
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="twelve columns">
          <h2> - Single Country -</h2>

          <table className="u-full-width">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>GFI</th>
                <th>Flag </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>{oneCountry.name}</td>
                <td>{oneCountry.GFI}</td>
                <td>
                  <img style={flagStyle} src={oneCountry.flagUrl} />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatch = dispatch => ({
  fetchCountry: countryId => {
    dispatch(fetchCountry(countryId));
  },
});

const mapState = state => ({
  oneCountry: state.oneCountry,
});

export default connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(SingleCountry);
```

My gut is telling me its either in my axios request or maybe some of the syntax for mapping and dispatching.

As an aside I do at least get a partial render (see below)...And no errors. Are there any precautions one could do for better diagnose?

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

**UPDATE**
This is how my `store.js` file looks like...

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import loggingMiddleware from 'redux-logger'; // https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'; // https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

import topFiveCountriesByGFIReducer from './reducers/topFiveCountriesByGFI';
import countriesReducer from './reducers/countries';
import oneCountryReducer from './reducers/oneCountry';

const middleware = [loggingMiddleware, thunkMiddleware];

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  topFiveCountries: topFiveCountriesByGFIReducer,
  countries: countriesReducer,
  oneCountry: oneCountryReducer,
});

export default createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)));
```

**UPDATE**

Recent error I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: `oneCountry` is an array, not a single object. Check your console and reducer.

Comment: I understand you mean I may be accessing it incorrectly but that doesn't explain the undefined values. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It explains the undefined values for `oneCountry.name` and `oneCountry.GFI`. Are you combining reducers? Is there more to it?

Comment: Also are you even dispatching `GET_COUNTRY`?

Comment: Scroll down on the `SingleCountry` view, the dispatches are there. I also added the other reducers for `TopFiveCountries` and `Countries`. I know using `react-redux` is probably overkill but my school is requiring us to use it.

Comment: You aren't dispatching the action. All you're doing is mapping dispatch to props. You actually have to call `this.props.fetchCountry(id)` to send the request.

Comment: Hey thanks, and I do that in the lifecycle methods? LIke so 
`componentDidMount(){   this.props.fetchCountry(id)   }` ?

Comment: I actually tried this: `componentDidMount() {
    const countryId = this.props.match.params.id;
    this.props.fetchCountry(countryId);
  }`
But that didn't work...

Comment: Yeah, that's good. I'd actually have a loading icon until the request finishes. I'm not familiar with Sequelize, but if you can you can wait until the dispatch finishes via promises (like with Redux thunk) then set state when it does finishes and get rid of the loading icon.

Comment: It didn't work because you aren't rerendering the component once the request does finish.

Comment: So I should take a look and my express endpoints and see how I am calling for the data with Sequelize? And then do some kind of conditional rendering on in the view with react?

Comment: Nevermind, this doesn't have anything to with Sequelize, I got mixed up. How are you doing the async action creators? With redux thunk?

Comment: Yes, I am going to update it above so you can see how my `store.js`  file looks like.

Answer (score 1):

So you aren't dispatching your action. You have to dispatch the action, and since it's asynchronous, it'd be good to show some kind of UI to indicate you're fetching from an API of some sort. Here's a trimmed down version:

```
class SingleCountry extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      loading: true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const countryId = this.props.match.params.id;
    dispatch(this.props.fetchCountry(countryId))
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const oneCountry = this.props.oneCountry;
    const loading = this.state.loading;
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="twelve columns">
          <h2> - Single Country -</h2>

          {
            !loading ?
              <table className="u-full-width">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>GFI</th>
                    <th>Flag </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>{oneCountry.name}</td>
                    <td>{oneCountry.GFI}</td>
                    <td>
                      <img style={flagStyle} src={oneCountry.flagUrl} />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            :
              <img src={LOADING ICON HERE} />
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapState = (state, ownProps) => ({
  oneCountry: state.oneCountry,
  ...ownProps
});
```

What this does is initially set state of `loading` to true. Then, when the component mounts, your request is sent to the API. Meanwhile, while the request is working, a loading icon will show up. Once the request is done, the `then` of the dispatch will execute and set state of `loading` to false. This will, in turn, rerender your component and show the table, with the appropriate data.

Also, notice `mapState` now uses a second argument - `ownProps`. The thing is, when you `connect` a component to the Redux store, you lose any props that are passed to the component. In this case, React Router passes the matched parameters to `SingleCountry` but it's lost due to `connect`. This can be solved by using the second argument of either `mapState` or `mapDispatch`. The second argument contains allow the props passed to the connected component, and you can spread them into the returned object to access them in your component.

Comment: Hey there—just wanted to say thanks for all your help. I think I am almost there! I got another error message that'll i post above. I've been at it all day....
I'll take a crack at it tomorrow with fresh eyes!

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz I edited the answer to include the fix.